# Reuse existing objects in django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

We want to reduce the amount of same object instances in one python interpreter.

Example:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

If we iterate the thousand blogs, the same (same id but different python object) author objects get created several times.

Is there a way to make the django ORM reuse the already created user instances?

Example:

```
for blog in Blog.objects.all():
    print (blog.author.username)
```

If author "foo-writer" has 100 blogs, there are 100 author objects in the memory. That's what we want to avoid.

I think solutions like mem-cached/redis won't help here, since we want to optimize the python process.

Comment: 1)https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

2)https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's database calls or memory usage you're concerned about here.

If the former, then using `select_related` will help you:

```
Blog.objects.all().select_related('author')
```

which will get all the blogs and their associated authors.

If you want to optimize memory, then the best way to do it is to get the relevant author objects manually in one go, store them in a dict, then manually annotate that object on each blog:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
author_ids = set(b.author_id for b in blogs)
authors = Author.objects.in_bulk(list(author_ids))
for blog in blogs:
    blog._author = authors[blog.author_id]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Concerns are unrelated to memory but related to runtime here. Both of your suggestions help to reduce it.

Is there a configuration meta option for models to turn on caching of related instances via pk? It looks cleaner to us and would be more generic than repeating these steps over and over again for all concerned related fields.

Comment: We ran some tests that back our presumption that re-using already created python objects is more efficient than recreating them (which e.g. 'select_related' does).